# Static fields - string interpolation using static

Tags: c#, .net, stylecop

```
public static class SomeRegexConsts
{
    public static readonly string FullName = $"{Name} {Surname}";

    private static readonly string Name = "[A-Z][a-z]+";

    private static readonly string Surname = "[A-Z][a-z]+";
}
```

In above example `FullName` will be equal to `" "` at runtime.
It's related to the way static fields are initialized (from top to bottom).

In general I don't see any other solution than changing it to a getter:

```
public static string FullName => $"{Name} {Surname}";
```

Any ideas how to improve this code as I don't like this lambda, and moving `FullName` below `Name` and `Surname` is not an option as StyleCop won't let me do this.

Comment: I hope this is just a simplified example, because those regex patterns won't match names in the real world.

Comment: Oh, yes, it is simplified. Actual regex is way longer but it is not a topic of this question

Comment: You do realize that there are names that have letters outside the range of `A-Z`?

Comment: Yes I do, but probably you do not realize that I've already answered this question :)

Comment: Who reads comments? Sorry, about asking the same question again. :)

Comment: No problem. Just to keep these questions away I've changed regexps :)

Comment: I have rollbacked, since your edit is more confusing than helping. IMHO

Comment: Sorry for reedit - I was confused and first thought was "I didn't save my changes"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to move  `FullName` below others, I think this's only solution for you.

```
public static class SomeRegexConsts
{
    static SomeRegexConsts(){
        FullName = $"{Name} {Surname}";
    }

    public static readonly string FullName;

    private static readonly string Name = "[A-Z][a-z]+";

    private static readonly string Surname = "[A-Z][a-z]+";
```

Answer (score 0):

What about creating a public method that returns the FullName string ?

```
public string getFullname()
{
    return $"{Name} {Surname}";
}
```

This way `public static readonly string FullName = $"{Name} {Surname}";`, if it's ok to get rid of it, won't be needed anymore.

Comment: yes, but it adds another method invocation for something that won't change

Answer (score 0):

I believe this would work with StyleCop since it requires `const` before fields of any type:

```
public static class SomeRegexConsts
{
    private const string Name = "[A-Z][a-z]+";
    private const string Surname = "[A-Z][a-z]+";

    public static readonly string FullName = $"{Name} {Surname}";

}
```

unless you're using reflection within the class that requires a non-const field, the compiled code should be unaffected.